# dplyr detect value outside range across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's take the following data

```
data <- tibble(a = letters[1:4], b1 = 10:13, b2 = 10:13, 
               b3 = c(9, 4, 11, 10), b4 = c(50, 10:12))
min <- 9
max <- 15

data
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  a        b1    b2    b3    b4
  <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        10    10     9    50
2 b        11    11     4    10
3 c        12    12    11    11
4 d        13    13    10    12
```

I want to create a new column `is_unexpected` to control if a value is outside of `min` & `max` range.

Of course, the slow (in the sense of writing the code) way to do it is the one below. Since I have more than 4 columns (which all begin with "b"), I'm looking to optimise my code. I've tried playing with `across()` but unsuccessfully.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(is_unexpected = 
           if_else(b1 < min | b2 < min | b3 < min | b4 < min | 
                     b1 > max | b2 > max | b3 > max | b4 > max,
                   1, 0)
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `if_any`:

```r
data %>% 
  mutate(is_unexpected = +(if_any(b1:b4, ~ .x > max | .x < min)))

# A tibble: 4 × 6
  a        b1    b2    b3    b4 is_unexpected
  <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>         <int>
1 a        10    10     9    50             1
2 b        11    11     4    10             1
3 c        12    12    11    11             0
4 d        13    13    10    12             0
```

Or with `between`:

```r
data %>% 
  mutate(is_unexpected = +(if_any(b1:b4, ~ !between(.x, min, max))))
```

Comment: Thank you ! I like that you should the inverse solution with `between()`.

Comment: If you want to count the number of unexpected values, I've used `data %>% mutate(is_unexpected = rowSums(across(b1:b4, ~ .x > max | .x < min)))` thanks to Maël's solution

Answer (score 3):

Using `across`

```
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(is_unexpected = any(across(b1:b4) > !!max | across(b1:b4) < !!min) * 1)
# A tibble: 4 × 6
# Rowwise: 
  a        b1    b2    b3    b4 is_unexpected
  <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
1 a        10    10     9    50             1
2 b        11    11     4    10             1
3 c        12    12    11    11             0
4 d        13    13    10    12             0
```

Using `!!` here because if the data frame has a *min* or *max* variable it uses these instead of the global ones.

Comment: First time I learn about the rowwise() function, very useful. Good to note that the final `*1` is to turn `TRUE` to 1. Also, I'm trying to find some explanation about the `!!`. Do you have a link?

Comment: @DanielMc You can read about `!!` in `rlang`, e.g. `?"injection-operator"`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively please check

```r
data %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(.x>min|.x>max, 1, 0), .names = 'new{col}'),
 is_unexpected= ifelse(rowSums(across(starts_with('new')))>0,1,0)) %>% 
select(-starts_with('new'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: there's a small typo, it should be `~ifelse(.x<min|...`. I found it difficult to understand until I ran it. Although the solution works, it does create the same number of columns I am trying to analyse. It's ok for 4 columns, but if I had a big database, this might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
data$is_expected <- +(rowSums(data[-1] > max) > 0|rowSums(data[-1] < min)> 0)
```

-output

```
> data
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  a        b1    b2    b3    b4 is_expected
  <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>       <int>
1 a        10    10     9    50           1
2 b        11    11     4    10           1
3 c        12    12    11    11           0
4 d        13    13    10    12           0
```

Comment: ah, the famous base R solution :) always useful, thx